# Problems opening PDF in Firefox using pdfmake and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

It seems to be a known issue that .download() for pdfmake does not work in Firefox (e.g. https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/378 or http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted). It is suggested to use .open() instead (see e.g. the above links). However, this does not work for me either in Firefox 50+ as it just produces a blank page. I wondered if someone could provide a pointer as how to make it work in Firefox (Chrome works fine)? Many thanks in advance.

Edit. I have narrowed my problem down. If I create a PDF from HTML via e.g.

```
     html2canvas(document.getElementById("id"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [
                {
                    image: data,
                    width: 500
                }], 
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
        }
    });
```

it just produces a blank page in Firefox but

```
    var docDefinition = {
        content: [{
            test: "Hello World
        }], 
    };
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

works fine. I am not sure what the reason is though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then updated to pdfmake 0.1.24 that solve the issue.